# unable to get property 'insertBefore' of null or undefined and AngularJS and UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

- I am using AngularJS v1.5.x and UI Router v0.2.18.
- I have the following config in the routes
- App Dependencies for app.config - `function appConfig ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider,httpServiceProvider,$mdThemingProvider)`

  ```
      $stateProvider
                  .state('home', {
                      url: "/",
                      templateUrl: "views/home.tmpl.html",
                      onEnter:function(httpService,$location,$state){
                          if(httpService.userid === null || httpService.userid === undefined){
                              httpService.token = encodeURIComponent($location.search().token);
                              httpService.assignUserId();
                              $state.go('home.intro');

                          }
                      }
                      })
                  .state('home.intro', {
                      url: "intro",
                      templateUrl: "views/home.intro.tmpl.html"
                      })
                  .state('home.menus', {
                      url: "menus",
                      templateUrl: "views/home.menus.tmpl.html"
                      })
  }
  ```
- I am using html5 mode as false.
- When I go from path.biz/#/ to path.biz/#/intro which is an auto redirect and this happens when the page loads - I am getting error `unable to get property 'insertBefore' of null or undefined` along with error error Invalid arguement before it.
- Is it to do with the config or the ui -router. Is this occuring due to a arguement that is not provided somewhere if so then is it HTML related or JS related? Unable to trace the error
- I am also using `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/intro');` when using non-html5 mode. Is this right notation or I have to use `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('#/intro');`?

  [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you change your URL to have the / notation:

```
 .state('home.intro', {
                url: "/intro",
                templateUrl: "views/home.intro.tmpl.html"
                })
```

Your default path is perfectly fine

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/intro');
```

You don't need to add the hash

NOTE: If this doesn't help you, could you create a fiddle with your code for people to see it live?

Comment: Ok so home will be / then home.intro will be /intro and home.menus will be /menus . is that right?

Comment: Correct. That's standard URL notation. Let's see if that solves your issue. If not we'll look at other ways